# How do I set git upstream on my git server

Tags: git

Say I cloned a repo foo from foo.com on my computer .

Then I added this repo to MyGitServer.com and ran these commands:

```
git remote add upstream https://foo.com/foo.git
git remote set-url origin https://MyGitServer.com/foo.git
```

How do I get these last two changes to MyGitServer.com such that if someone clones foo from MyGitServer.com, the upstream is correct? Right now if I clone, the origin will be foo.com, not MyGitServer.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring remotes is a local operation that must be run on the system that cloned the repo.

It's not something that can come along with the clone automatically.

So, each user will need to separately run those commands.